# How to assign value at run time in AWK command

Tags: shell-script, awk, variable

I am using below command to remove line feeds with in field values.This sample commmand created for file having 3 attributes.

```
awk -F\| '{while(NF<3 && getline p)$0=$0 p}1'
```

My input filess having different number of attributes, so I want to parameterize number of attributes value in AWK command. I tried like below but getting error.

```
NoAttributes=12
awk -F\| '{while(NF<$NoAttributes && getline p)$0=$0 p}1'
```

Error Details:

> awk: Field  is not correct.
>
> The input line number is 1.
>
> The source line number is 1.

Answer (score 3):

To set an `awk` variable on the command line, use `-v variable=value`:

```
awk -v attrs=2 '{ ... NF < attrs && ... }'
```

You may also access environment variables by using `ENVIRON["variable"]` in the `awk` code:

```
export attrs=2
awk '{ ... NF < ENVIRON["attrs"] && ... }'
```

or,

```
attrs=2 awk '{ ... NF < ENVIRON["attrs"] && ... }'
```

or,

```
env attrs=2 awk '{ ... NF < ENVIRON["attrs"] && ... }'
```

The last two variations would not set `attrs` in the invoking environment, only for the `awk` program (and any processes it may possibly start).

A third way is to give `variable=value` as a "filename" argument:

```
awk '...' msg="hello" file1 file2 msg="good bye" file3 file4
```

This would set the `awk` variable `msg` to the string `hello` before starting to process the file `file1`.  It would retain that value until the value is change to `good bye` just before processing `file3`.  Note that variables set in this way would not be available inside any `BEGIN` block in the `awk` code.

Injecting shell variables directly into the `awk` code by means of a variable expansion in the string that constitutes the code is not a good way of transferring data into an `awk` program, and should be avoided.