# Add basename to output files

Tags: bash, scripting, variable

I have a script which processes input files and generates an output file. I want the basename of each file to be part of the output file, but it isn't working:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
tmp_header="tmp_header"
echo "Processing $line"
Sample_name=`basename -s .fastq.gz $line`
gsutil cat $line | zcat | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":"} {lane=$4 ; print > "${Sample_name}.lane."lane".fastq.gz" ; for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {getline ; print > "${Sample_name}.lane."lane".fastq.gz"}}'
done < "test.list.paths.Bcancer2.txt"


$ cat test.list.paths.Bcancer2.txt
gs://fc-0e96c1b9-ba10-44f3-8b07-91a4c1a5cf14/10002/10002_R1.fastq.gz
```

output file

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xkwaku001 2.2G Jul  8 05:54 '${Sample_name}.lane.2.fastq.gz'
```

but I want my results to be like this:

```
$ 10002_R1.lane.2.fastq.gz
```

thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to be asking about [How to assign value at run time in AWK command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496870/65304)

Answer (score 2):

Cutting to what seems to be important part, you have:

```
Sample_name=something
awk '{lane=$4 ; print > "${Sample_name}.lane."lane".fastq.gz"; ...}'
#   ^                   *                    *                     ^
```

and you probably want awk to use the value of the shell variable `Sample_name` in the filename there. The shell doesn't expand that variable, because it's inside a single-quoted string. (And if it was double-quoted, you'd need to escape the double-quotes and dollar signs in the script.) Awk also doesn't expand that, because it's in a double quoted string in the awk script (and it's shell syntax, not awk syntax).

So, the easiest way to get that done is to pass the shell variable to awk, with `awk -v`, and to use it in the awk script like you're now using `line`. A simplified example:

```
Sample_name=foobar
awk -v SN="$Sample_name" 'BEGIN {lane=123; print SN ".lane." lane ".fastq.gz" }'
```

Running that would print `foobar.lane.123.fastq.gz`.

Comment: this was helpful! thanks +1!

Answer (score 2):

You are using the *shell* variable `$sample_name` inside the awk script, but awk doesn't have access to that variable. What's more, since it's quoted, awk will treat it as a string which is what you see. Here's a working version of your script:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    tmp_header="tmp_header"
    echo "Processing $line"
    Sample_name=$(basename -s .fastq.gz "$line")
    gsutil cat "$line" | zcat | 
        awk -v sname="$Sample_name" '
            BEGIN {FS = ":"} 
            {
                lane=$4;
                fileName = sname".lane."lane".fastq.gz" 
                print > fileName
                for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                    getline
                    print > fileName
                }
            }'
done < test.list.paths.Bcancer2.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm certain that if you replace the single quotes with double-quotes and escape the quotes inside your awk program, you'll be a lot happier. Additionally, you can specify the field separator for a run of awk with -F and avoid having to set it in the BEGIN block, and instead of typing `cat $line | zcat ...` you can type `zcat $line ...` to avoid a [useless use of cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

I hope this helps!